# Canonical examples of successful scientists giving detailed advice about doing science/mathematics?

Tags: scientists

I've read this long transcript of a speech given by Richard Hamming:

http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/YouAndYourResearch.html

It was an amazingly good speech in my view, and extremely interesting.

So my question is: **Do you know of more articles like this? Articles or transcripts of speeches by successful scientists giving their life's wisdom and advice in condensed form?** I've read a lot of philosophy and history of science, and while that is very interesting, supplementing it with more practical insights by scientists (rather than philosophers or historians of science) is helpful.

Comment: You might want to supplement such reading with something such as https://xkcd.com/1827/

Comment: Poincare wrote several books on the philosophy of science and of mathematics.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Poincar%C3%A9#Poincar%C3%A9's_writings_in_English_translation

Answer (score 2):

Gian-Carlo Rota, Ten lessons I wish I had been taught, published in his book
Indiscrete thoughts, Springer 2008 (can be also found on Internet).

Comment: very good :) more of this.

Answer (score 1):

Santiago Ramón y Cajal wrote [*Reglas y consejos sobre investigación científica*](https://cvc.cervantes.es/ciencia/cajal/cajal_reglas/default.htm), translated into English as *Advice for a Young Investigator*.